# Como buscar todas as associações em uma árvores de relacionamentos no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-rotas

Estou tendo um dilema.
Tenho tabelas que se relacionam, tipo:

**internal_clients->subsidiaries->departments->job_titles->users**

Tenho também seus Respectivos models.

**Minha dúvida é:**

Como faço para pegar todos os dados associados aos users desde o topo da cadeia (internal_clients) ?

Estou tentando seguir a documentação do Laravel utilizando o hasManyThrough.

Porém na doc explica somente a forma de se fazer em uma cadeia de 3 tabelas. Ensinam a colocar uma tabela (model) intermediária como segundo parâmetro do método hasManyThrough(ClasseBase::class, ClasseIntermediaria:class).

Porém, no meu caso que tem várias tabelas entre users e internal_clients, como eu faria isso ? Qual seria a tabela intermediária ?

Eu gostaria de fazer uma consulta que retornasse qual o internal_client, subsidiary, department e jobTitle do user (associados aos users).

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma:

**Model InternalClient**

```
public function users()
 {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, InternalClient::class);
 }
```

**Controller UserController**

```
 public function allRelations($internalClientId)
 {
     $internalClient = InternalClient::find($internalClientId);
       
      $users = $internalClient->users;

      return response()->json($users, 201);
 }
```

- O id da InternalClient chega no controller acima.

Quando eu acesso a **rota**, me é retornado o **erro abaixo:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resumindo:** Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de pegar todos os dados (de todas as tabelas que estão nessa árvore hierárquica) que estão associados ao Usuário.

Obrigado!

Comment: É difícil te ajudar sem entender primeiro a lógica dos relacionamentos, porque o que vc está tentando fazer no seu código é pegar todos os `internal_clients` que se relacionam com `users`. De uma forma geral, dada sua estrutura relacional, a melhor opção seja usar `join` mesmo

Comment: Estou tentando fazer uma lógica mais ou menos assim: https://paste.laravel.io/fa0089c6-7e18-415e-8f63-f86af867d324

Comment: `$internalClients->departments->sections->jobTitles->users` da a entender que **internalClients** tem um **departments** que tem um **sections** que tem um **jobTitles** que pode ter vários **users**, seria a única forma disso funcionar

Comment: Se sua realidade não igua à acida vc vai precisar fazer **join** mesmo https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: Na verdade seria: "interbalClients" pode ter vários "departments" que pode ter vários "sections" que pode ter vários "jobTitles" e que pode ter vários "users". Como vc colocou negrito no comentário ? <b></b> ?

Comment: Então sua melhor alternativa é realmente usar **Join**

Comment: E with ? Me recomendaram fazer com with e está me parecendo ficar um código mais limpo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar vários níveis de relacionamento usando o hasManyThrough, que na verdade somente consegue relacionar através "trough" um único subnível. Veja que p erro está informando que não existe id fk na tabela internal client, quando na verdade, por esta linha que você postou `internal_clients->subsidiaries->departments->job_titles->users`, parece-me que o relacionamento (fk) está em job_titles.

Com o que você postou de informações, abstraindo os modelo de dados mentalmente, eu diria que você consegue um relacionamento do tipo hasManyTrough apenas em `departments` usando `job_title`.

Então realmente terá que ir de join entre as várias tabelas que se ligam de internal_clientes até users.

Mas faz assim, cria um método no modelo de internal_clients que monte um scope para que vc possa utilizar:

```
function scopeUsers($query) {
    return $query->join("subsidiaries", "fk-de-subsidiaries-em-internal-clients", "=", "pk-em-subsidiaries")
                 ->join("departments", "fk-de-departments-em-subsidiaries", "=", "pk-em-departments")
                 ->join("job_titles", "fk-de-job_titles-em-departments", "=", "pk-em-job_titles")
                 ->join("users", "fk-de-users-em-job_titles", "=", "pk-em-job_titles");
}
```

Pode ser que não esteja 100% aderente ao seu modelo pois você não o postou aqui.

Para verificar a documentação sobre o Joins - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Para verificar a documentação sobre escopos (scopes) - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Estou seguindo um conselho aqui de utilizar o with(). Parece que está dando certo até agora. Estou terminando pra ver, Ademir.

Comment: Se solucionar de forma diferente, poste sua resposta para que outros possam decidir a melhor solução em situações semelhantes, valeu

Answer (score 0):

Tentei fazer com **with**. Porém retornava toda a cadeia de relacionamentos. **Veja:**

```
public function allRelations($internalClientId)
{               
   $internalClients = InternalClient::with('departments.sections.jobTitles.users')->find($internalClientId);
   return response()->json($internalClients , 201);
}
```

**O retorno era esse:**

https://paste.laravel.io/b3c80b26-f37f-4e56-9f60-5535379f73d9

Então tentei fazer com os **Joins**, conforme a resposta do outro rapaz (*Por isso vou aceitá-la*). **Veja:**

```
public function allRelations($internalClientId)
{              
     $internalClients = InternalClient::join('departments', 'departments.internal_client_id','=','internal_client_id')
     ->join('sections', 'sections.department_id','=','departments.id')  
     ->join('job_titles', 'job_titles.section_id','=','sections.id') 
     ->join('users', 'users.job_title_id','=','job_titles.id')
     ->select(                                            
              'users.id AS user_id',
              'users.name AS user_name',
              'users.surname AS user_surname',
              'users.email AS user_email',
              'departments.id AS department_id' ,
              'departments.name AS department_name',
              'sections.id AS section_id', 
              'sections.name AS section_name', 
              'job_titles.id AS job_title_id',  
              'job_titles.name AS job_title_name'                                                  
              )
      ->where('internal_client_id',$internalClientId) 
      ->groupBy('users.id')     
      ->get();    
    
       return response()->json($internalClients, 201);
}
```

**E a saída foi essa:**

```
[
  {
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_name": "GLEISIANE",
    "user_surname": "ROUCAS",
    "user_email": "gleici@gmail.com",
    "department_id": 2,
    "department_name": "FISCAL",
    "section_id": 1,
    "section_name": "CONTABIL - SETOR 1",
    "job_title_id": 1,
    "job_title_name": "AUXILIAR CONTÁBIL"
  },
  {
    "user_id": 2,
    "user_name": "ANDREWS",
    "user_surname": "RIBEIRO",
    "user_email": "andrews@gmail.com",
    "department_id": 2,
    "department_name": "FISCAL",
    "section_id": 1,
    "section_name": "CONTABIL - SETOR 1",
    "job_title_id": 1,
    "job_title_name": "AUXILIAR CONTÁBIL"
  }
]
```

- Queria fazer com o **with**, sei que dá, mas infelizmente não consegui. Então resolvi fazer logo com o Join para não atrasar o trabalho.